# Struts - JSP - Enabling/Disabling Button and Textbox based on Status of checkbox, using Java Script

Tags: javascript, jsp, checkbox, struts

I am using struts framework in my project. Have Used one check box, one button and one text box on my JSP. Below is the code for all of them.

```
<html:text  name="FormBean" styleId = "codeERText" property="codeER" onFocus="change_classe_byId(this,'on');" onBlur="change_classe_byId(this,'off');" styleClass="off" maxlength="5"/>

<input type="button" styleId = "deduireButton" name = "deduireButton" id = "deduireButton" value="<bean:message key="Property.deduire"/>"   onClick="javascript:validate('DEDUIRE');">

<html:checkbox styleId="idBrodcastCheckbox" property="sentToAll" name="FormBean" onChange="javascript:broadcastValidate();"  />
```

Requirement is when check box is checked, it should disable the button and textbox and vice-verse.

Below is the function which is being called at onChange Event of Checkbox.. 
While running this on Application, it just gives first alert ("Inside Broadcast Validate").. No other alerts are raised.. Nor the button or text box is being disabled. I believe, it is not entering in any of the If/Else pairs.

App Server used is Weblogic 8.1.

```
function broadcastValidate(){

    alert("Inside Broadcast Validate");
    if(document.forms[0].idBrodcastCheckbox.checked == true)
    {
        alert("checked true");
        document.forms[0].codeERText.disabled = true;
        document.forms[0].deduireButton.disabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("checked false");
        document.forms[0].codeERText.disabled = false;
        document.forms[0].deduireButton.disabled = false;
    }

    alert("First If over");

    if(this.document.FormBean.getElementById("idBrodcastCheckbox").checked == true)
    {
        alert("checked true 2");
        this.document.getElementById("codeERText").disabled = true;
        this.document.getElementById("deduireButton").disabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("checked false 2");
        this.document.getElementById("codeERText").disabled = false;
        this.document.getElementById("deduireButton").disabled = false;
    }
    alert("Second If over ");

    if(document.forms[0].sentToAll.value == true)
    {
        alert("checked true - Sent to All");
        document.forms[0].codeERText.disabled = true;
        document.forms[0].deduireButton.disabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("checked false - Sent to All");
        document.forms[0].codeERText.disabled = false;
        document.forms[0].deduireButton.disabled = false;
    }

    alert("Third If over - Exiting Broadcast Validate");
}
```

Please suggest some solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitely won't be `this.document.FormBean.getElementById()` because `getElementById()` is a method on document. To get an element by id, which is what I'd do in this case, use:

```
document.getElementById('idBrodcastCheckbox')
```

You should not need to specify the `name` attribute in the checkbox; by default, properties are assumed to exist on the action's `ActionForm`. Unless you're specifically doing something differently, use the defaults of the framework.

If you're not even getting the `"First If over"` alert, then check your JavaScript console.

Comment: Thanks Dave.. I modified the code and used document.getElementById('idBrodcastCheckbox')
as suggested. It works fine now.. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and `document.forms[0].idBrodcastCheckbox.checked` returns `true`. When you say that nothing other than `"Inside Broadcast Validate"` is being alerted, possibly there happens an error after the first alert statement. As Dave has mentioned, use your Javascript console to see any errors. Also, check if you have missed the `html:form` tag where the elements should be kept inside.